# Lualatex : € as a utf8 character is not recognized : why?

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I need to include some tex files as parts of a more global project. Some of this global projects have to be compiled with pdflatex, some others with lualatex, but the parts are the same. All this part files are written with a € as an utf8 character. I would like avoid to replace them by a `\texteuro`.

Is there a way to make lualatex understand € as a `\texteuro` ?

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \RequirePackage{luacode}
\else
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\RequirePackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
36\,\texteuro % works with both pdflatex lualatex

36\,€ % doesn't work with lualatex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps something like Ctrl + H ? :)

Comment: I have a thousand files with such a remplacement to make. I can run a pearl script to make the changes. But if there is a simple solution to do this it is wellcome. One could ask why lualatex doesn't accept all utf8 characters ? Is there other characters that lualatex doesn't accept ?

Comment: I can no possibility of checking now, hence only a suggestion. Does 
\catcode`\€=\active
\def€{your euro, e.g. \texteuro}
€ work for you?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke no, it gives `36 your euro` and an infinite loop if a remplace your euro by € ;-)

Comment: @Tarass Of course you should replace not by 
€, but by `\texteuro` or other command which produces the symbol.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Sorry I didn't understand, yes it works. Thank you.

Comment: I've written a script that converts Unicode Tex files into Ascii Tex files that use charnum quoting (i.e. non-ascii characters get represented by ascii codes along the lines of \char"20AC), which could easily adapted to convert a file to use \texteuro instead.  Would this be of interest?  I'd need to dig up the script, can't find it right now...

Comment: @CharlesStewart I thank you very much, I prefer not to convert my files (one could aesily do that with a pearl script). The problem was how to have € as an utf8 character in lualatex. The package proposed by Harish Kumar is a good solution because one can reuse it for other hypthetic problems.

Comment: Tarass: You don't need to convert your input files, but can generate intermediate files via conversion, which works well in a Makefile.

Comment: @CharlesStewart The simplest way is to leave them as is, isn't it ? thank you anyway.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem with the latest TL2014; `fourier` doesn't work with luaTeX, though (`Command `\hbar' already defined.`).

Comment: @MartinSchröder I had it again yesterday when Harish Kumar send his answer, but today I can not found how to reproduce it ... if it comes again I'll tell you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `newunicodechar` package and define

```
\newunicodechar{€}{\texteuro}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \RequirePackage{luacode}
\else
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
\let\hbar\hhhbar    %% without this I get a warning
\RequirePackage{fourier}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{€}{\texteuro}

\begin{document}
36\,\texteuro % works with both pdflatex lualatex

36\,€ % doesn't work with lualatex
\end{document}
```

Then it should work in both pdflatex and lualatex.

Comment: It doesn't come from your code, but from a known clash between fourier and some math fonts. One has to load some math fonts **before** fourier. I have `\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs}` before `fourier` package in my `.sty`.

Answer (score 18):

With `\usepackage{fourier}` you are simply ignoring `fontspec` and using a family of “classical” 256 character font.

You can use classical fonts with LuaLaTeX, without loading `fontspec`, but `luainputenc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc} % load TS1 so luainputenc will know
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{luacode}
  \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi

\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
36\,\texteuro % works with both pdflatex lualatex

36\,€ % doesn't work with lualatex
\end{document}
```

Of course this will not use the full strengths of LuaLaTeX as regards to fonts, but it's impossible anyway if you want your document to be processable with LuaLaTeX and pdfLaTeX (and loading `luacode` doesn't make much sense).

A probably better solution is to use a text font replacement for Utopia, such as the very recent Erewhon font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{luacode}
  \usepackage{fourier}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Erewhon}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{fourier}
\fi


\begin{document}
36\,\texteuro % works with both pdflatex lualatex

36\,€ % doesn't work with lualatex

Some math $a+\mathrm{a}=\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I will not adopt it by now, because `Erewhon` is a very young package and is not support in texlive, that means that the solution is not immediatly portable. But I keep it in mind and the explantions you've give with.

Comment: @Tarass Erewhon *is* in TeX Live. There's also Heuristica, which is similar.

Comment: `tlmgr` didn't find it on ` http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet`. I change of depository, and now it's ok.

Answer (score 4):

As it is already verified, I put also my solution, suggested in comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\catcode`\€=\active
\def€{\texteuro} 
\begin{document}
36 €
\end{document}
```

> [image]